# How to stop a handler and its runnable when it is initiated via Apply{}

Tags: android, kotlin, apply

I made the following function to generate a handler event every 15 seconds. It starts with a given flag, when I pass False I want the handler to stop its loop. Here is my code snippet in Kotlin:

```
private fun getSalesData(session:Boolean,delayMs:Long,salesRequest: JsonObjectRequest){
        lateinit var runnable: Runnable
        if (session) {
            HttpRequestSingleton.getInstance(this@NavBarActivity).addToRequestQueue(salesRequest)
        }
        Handler().apply {
            runnable = object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    HttpRequestSingleton.getInstance(this@NavBarActivity).addToRequestQueue(salesRequest)
                    Log.d(TAG, "se esta repitiendo cada 15 segs mamahuevo")
                    postDelayed(this, delayMs)
                }
            }
            postDelayed(runnable, delayMs)
            if (!session){
                Log.d(TAG,"entre aca como todo un crack")
                Handler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable)
            }
        }
        if(!session){
            Log.d(TAG,"aanopqwwwwww")
            Handler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what exactly you want to do, but here is possible solution:

```
private fun getSalesData(session:Boolean,delayMs:Long,salesRequest: JsonObjectRequest){
        lateinit var runnable: Runnable
        if (session) {
            HttpRequestSingleton.getInstance(this@NavBarActivity).addToRequestQueue(salesRequest)
        }
        Handler().apply {
            runnable = object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    HttpRequestSingleton.getInstance(this@NavBarActivity).addToRequestQueue(salesRequest)
                    Log.d(TAG, "se esta repitiendo cada 15 segs mamahuevo")
                    postDelayed(this, delayMs)
                }
            }
            postDelayed(runnable, delayMs)
            if (!session){
                Log.d(TAG,"entre aca como todo un crack")
                removeCallbacks(runnable) // just call this method, as part of your handler object 
            }
        }
        if(!session){
            Log.d(TAG,"aanopqwwwwww")
            removeCallbacks(runnable)// just call this method, as part of your handler object 
        }
    }
```

Update: Sorry, didn't see, that you used `removeCallbacksAndMessages`. `removeCallbacks` will remove any queued runnables

Comment: Yeah, i tried using removeCallbacks but its not working. My guess it needs a special way to be called with apply{} instance. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Don't use Handler(). before calling this method in apply{}